# Point cloud density

Tags: qgis, point, density, cloud-gis

I would like to compute the density in mm2 of a point cloud uploaded to QGIS. Is there a way to do this?

The file format is ASCII, and has been uploaded to QGIS via the text delimited uploader. Is there any way to obtain a value for the density in mm2?

Attached is the first few rows from the file.

[image]

Comment: In *square millimeters*? What's wrong with MKS units for geodata?

Comment: Can you add the first 20 rows or so from the text file?